# Comment box highlight goes wrong after more comments show up

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Why is the *Add Comment* box highlight goes `100%` after some more comments are posted on the post? Generally this happens when we click on *1/2 More Comment* option appears. I've attached a screen to describe the issue well...

[image]

[image]

---

**FIREBUG SCREEN**
[image]

> Browser: Firefox 22.0
>
> OS : Windows 7 Ultimate SP1

Comment: What browser? What OS? This on all questions? All answers? Everywhere? I can't repro on latest Chrome, Windows 7.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question where you noticed the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Everywhere since last few days, thought I should throw up to meta

Comment: On Chrome, when I click `add / show X more comments`, I see them and get the text box. The link isn't there anymore.

Comment: @Oded give me 5 mins, will throw up the sequence

Comment: I guess it happens on meta as well, can you post 1-2 dummy comments please

Comment: Dummy comment #1

Comment: Dummy comment #2 (damn timer reset!)

Comment: Oh yes, after clicking on show more I get comment box, now am confused how this happens, not even sure this happens here anymore, but I do encounter this issue since4-5 days, may be more on SO using ff

Comment: Is that only when the live update "add/ show X comments" comes up?

Comment: Waiting for the animated gif. I can't repro it either.

Comment: @Oded well, not sure now, am getting confused.. *sigh* but this happens, and that's for sure

Comment: Got it got it wait, this happens when am editing my comment, and than if someone adds a comment, and while the edit box is open and if I click to show more comments, this happens wait I'll put up the screen

Comment: Hmmm. If you can find a reliable repro, that will help. In the meantime, I have found another bug thanks to this ;)

Comment: Damn my boss was on my desk, lol so I've added the screen now

Comment: But how did you come to have it? Unless we have exact steps to reproduce, it's [meta-tag:status-norepro].

Comment: Well, this is getting lil randomized now, but somethings wrong with CSS, will throw up the CSS here using firebug

Comment: @Oded I guess, `display: block;` is added to the comment, probably jQuery is modifying the dom there, this never happens on refresh, so it's JS which must be adding block ... [off-topic] [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120941/1542290) guy is stealing my fiddle, changing the hex and answered the question, I want you to smack him a bit by commenting on his answer

Comment: @Oded nailed that, see the attached screen, as I told you, jQuery is messing up by adding `block`

Comment: Can you repro this on meta?

Comment: hello hello hello

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at this now.  The comments container has been a bit of a moving target over the last few days, so it's not really surprising that it's difficult to reproduce.  I'll try to reproduce, but it's likely fixed as a result of changes made to address other bugs.  I'll update when I feel like I have a more definitive answer.

**Update**:  I have been unable to reproduce this - although I suspect it was a legit bug at the time it was first posted.  I'll mark it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) instead of [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: Poor Ben. Do you remember what it was like when you *weren't* working on comment bugs? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: It keeps me up at night, actually.  Nowadays, every time a comment bug comes up, I have to ask myself: do I want to keep playing whack-a-mole, or is it time for a rewrite?

Comment: @BenCollins I still get it, nothing to do with my system, get that at my office too..

Comment: @BenCollins I'm also still seeing the race condition symptom I described to you earlier, but it's not consistent enough to describe a repro. And after it happens, I try to repro with Camtasia recording my screen, and it never works in that scenario. :-(

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I probably jumped the gun just a bit - there's another fix in the on-deck circle.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you need to clap your hands, twice, to reproduce it! ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: The fix was pushed after that last comment